# Can I have Gangadhareshwara Idol (not the Linga) to perform Abhyanjana, Abhisheka and pura?

Tags: shiva, idols

I'm worshiping our family deity Jaganmaate Omshree Gangadevi and I'm the priestess too. I, now want to install Lord Gangadhareshwara in idol form (not the Linga form). What are the steps I need to take.

Comment: So do u want prana pratishtha mantras or something else? And what is Pura?